# LinkedList.cpp:6:8: error: âLinkedListâ does not name a type

Tags: c++

I've just started writing the .cpp file of my class, but my compiler doesn't seem to recognize the default constructor or the class for that matter.
So here is what I have.

```
     //LinkedList.h
     #ifdef Linked_List
     #define Linked_List

     typedef int Node::element;
     #include "Node.h"
     #include <iostream>

     class LinkedList{
             public:
     //Default 
                     LinkedList();
     //Checks if empty
                     bool empty();
     //Inserts [Element] in front;
                     void insertFront(Element e)
     //Prints out all [Element]s in LinkedList
                     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList x);
     //Removes [Element] from the front of the list  
                     Element removeFront();
     //Removes [ELement] from the back of the list
                     Element removeBack();
     //Inserts an  [Element] at position 'i'
                     void insertAt(Element e, int i);
     //Removes an [Element] at position 'i'
                     Element  removeAt(int i);
     //Finds the [Element] 'e' and returns its position
                     int find(Element e);

             private:
                     Node *first;
                     Node *last;


     }; 




     #endif
```

And this is the cpp code. 
I have not instantiated the rest of the class yet because I can't get the default constructor working.

```
     //Inside LinkedList.cpp      
     #include "LinkedList.h"
     using namespace std;


     //Default Constructor
            LinkedList:: LinkedList(){
     //              first = nullptr;
     //              last = nullptr;

             }
```

I'v looked over this for an hour now and still can't figure it out. If you guys can help me, i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure what that `typedef` is doing there. That should be inside `Node`.

Answer (score 2):

Your include guard is wrong. You need

```
#ifndef Linked_List
```

instead of

```
#ifdef Linked_List
```

The effect is that your header is not correctly included in `LinkedList.cpp` by the pre-processor.

Comment: ARE YOU SERIOUS. ...Thank you . I feel like an idiot...